# How to Fix facebook error code 3703

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I created javascript facebook sdk for user login and share.
I got message from facebook developer team.

```
Your app is receiving errors from Follow Plugin


In the last three hours 100% of the calls to the method Follow Plugin resulted in errors.

Error Code


3703

Error Description


Invalid Publisher ID

Error Count


36017

This may be result of a recent change you made to Contact iMyanmarAds, or a failure to comply with a recent breaking change.

For more information about error codes and recovery tactics, please visit our documentation.

If the error rate has not been resolved after 3 days, we'll send you another alert.


You can view this and other Developer Notifications related to your app, in the App Dashboard.
```

I don't know why facebook team send me this message and how can I fix this error.

Comment: where is your code and/or your test page? please be more specific.

Comment: http://www.imyanmarhouse.com/what-kind-of-house-will-you-get  Here is my test page.